# Application Error trying to deploy site to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

While trying to deploy a simple site in Azure got this error message after deployment:

> :( Application Error
> If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can refer to a similar issue: [Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/67581/34-application-error-if-you-are-the-application-ad.html)

Comment: We're going to need a bit more details on this. Like where are you getting the error, and when? On the actual deploy, or if you go to the site? Are your versions of frameworks set correctly? Please refer to [ask].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using CI/CD to deploy your application, In the deploy task remove the slot name and replace the package with application file. Below are the samples:

**From:**

```
- name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'hello-world-app-to-delete'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: $
        package: .
```

**To:**

```
- name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'hello-world-app-to-delete'
        publish-profile: $
        package: ./dist/hello-world-app
```

For more information refer to this [GIT blog](https://nicolgit.github.io/how-deploy-angular-app-to-azure-appservice-running-linux-from-github/)

And to figure out what is the problem you can [enable diagnostics logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) in apps for azure app service. Also we can monitor our apps with [Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

@SaiKarri-MT gave me a little nudge, but I was using Azure DevOps instead of GitHub, so here's what worked for me in Azure DevOps, and the question is tagged with Azure DevOps and not github.

I was using Azure DevOps, so the other answer basically guided me to looking at the documentation for the tasks and making sure I was using everything the documentation recommended. I added startupCommand and the deploymentMethod. With a little experimentation I found my problem was the startupCommand I had configured in the portal. Leaving it out of the yaml leaves the incorrect startupCommand in the resource config.

**from:**

```yaml
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'mysub'
        appType: 'webAppLinux'
        appName: 'myapp'
        package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/myapp.zip'
```

**to:**

```yaml
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'mysub'
        appType: 'webAppLinux'
        startUpCommand: ''
        appName: 'myapp'
        package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/myapp.zip'
        deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
```

The [guide for deploying it via yaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?tabs=yaml) leaves out the two additional properties, but the [documentation for the task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) did have the information, although it wasn't in the examples. I had to look at the information for each of the properties.